# Shingles in Elasticsearch which respect punctuation

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am building an address matching engine for UK addresses in Elasticsearch and have found shingles to be very useful however I am seeing some issues when it comes to punctuation.  A query for "4 Walmley Close" is returning the following matches:

1. Units 3 And 4, Walmley Chambers, 3 Walmley Close
2. Flat 4, Walmley Court, 10 Walmley Close
3. Co-Operative Retail Services Ltd, 4 Walmley Close

The true match is number 3, however both 1 and 2 match (falsely) as they both become '4 walmley' when turned into shingles.  I would like to tell the shingle analyzer not generate shingles that straddle commas.  So, for example 1) currently I get:

- units 3
- 3 and
- and 4
- 4 walmley
- walmley chambers
- chambers 3
- 3 walmley
- walmley close

...when in actual fact all I want is....

- units 3
- 3 and
- and 4
- walmley chambers
- 3 walmley
- walmley close

My current settings are below.  I have experimented with swapping the tokenizer from standard to whitespace, this helps in that it retains the commas and would potentially avoid the situation above (i.e. I end up with '4, walmley' as my shingle in address 1 and 2) however I end up with lots of unusable shingles in my index and with 70 million documents I need to keep the index size down.

As you can see in the index settings I have also have a street_sym filter which I would love to be able to use in my shingles e.g. for this example, in addition to generating 'walmley close' I would like to have 'walmley cl' however when I attempted to include this I got shingles of 'close cl' which were not terribly helpful!

Any advice from more experienced Elasticsearch users would be hugely appreciated.  I have read through Gormley and Tong's excellent book but cannot get my head around this particular issue.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

```
"analysis": {
    "filter": {
        "shingle": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "output_unigrams": false
        },
        "street_sym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
                "st => street",
                "rd => road",
                "ave => avenue",
                "ct => court",
                "ln => lane",
                "terr => terrace",
                "cir => circle",
                "hwy => highway",
                "pkwy => parkway",
                "cl => close",
                "blvd => boulevard",
                "dr => drive",
                "ste => suite",
                "wy => way",
                "tr => trail"
            ]
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "shingle": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "shingle"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you got just the ones you wanted, "4 Walmley Close" would still match all three, since it gets tokenized to "4 walmley" and "walmley close", the latter of which still appears in all three.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment on your question for why the solution still won't stop "4 Walmley Close" from matching all three of the matches you provided. However, it is possible to at least get the tokens you want. I'm not sure it it's the most elegant/performant solution, but using the [Pattern Replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html), [Pattern Capture](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html), and [Length](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-length-tokenfilter.html) filters on your shingles seems to do the trick:

```js
"analysis": {
    "filter": {
        "shingle": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "output_unigrams": false
        },
        "street_sym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
                "st => street",
                "rd => road",
                "ave => avenue",
                "ct => court",
                "ln => lane",
                "terr => terrace",
                "cir => circle",
                "hwy => highway",
                "pkwy => parkway",
                "cl => close",
                "blvd => boulevard",
                "dr => drive",
                "ste => suite",
                "wy => way",
                "tr => trail"
            ]
        },
        "no_middle_comma": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": ".+,.+",
            "replacement": "" 
        },
        "no_trailing_comma": {
            "type": "pattern_capture",
            "preserve_original": false,
            "patterns": [
                "(.*),"
            ]
        },
        "not_empty": {
            "type": "length",
            "min": 1
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "test": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "street_sym",
                "shingle",
                "no_middle_comma",
                "no_trailing_comma",
                "not_empty"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- `no_middle_comma`: replace any tokens with a comma in the middle with an empty token
- `no_trailing_comma`: replace any tokens ending with a comma with the part before the comma
- `not_empty`: remove any empty tokens resulting from the above

For example, "Units 3 And 4, Walmley Chambers, 3 Walmley Cl" becomes:

```js
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "units 3",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 7,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "3 and",
         "start_offset": 6,
         "end_offset": 11,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "and 4",
         "start_offset": 8,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "walmley chambers",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 32,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "3 walmley",
         "start_offset": 33,
         "end_offset": 42,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 6
      },
      {
         "token": "walmley close",
         "start_offset": 35,
         "end_offset": 45,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 7
      }
   ]
}
```

Note that your synonym filter works: "Walmley Cl" became "walmley close".